# React-native-maps not showing google maps stylization on iOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

I implemented react-native-maps on a react project but seems that on iOS emulator it does not show google maps but the iOS default map even though I have a google maps API. I styled the map with a JSON file provided by google: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com but on the iOS emulator the map gets it default stylization. How can I style the map to fit both platforms?

Comment: Can you share some code? I can help you because recently worked with map.

Comment: I have just imported MapView from react-native-maps and also added the json file of the map stylization to make the map color grey. on android is ok but on ios it does not get the stylization provided by the json file taken by https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com. Please help me how to make the map color grey on both platforms